How to call operator= or destructor of superclass?
I have this A class with a heap member 'name':
class A {
protected:
    char *name;

public:
    // Constructor
    A() {
        name = new char[10];
        strcpy(name, "Undefined");
    }

    // Assignment Operator
    virtual A &operator=(const A &rhs) {
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }

        delete [] name;
        name = new char[10];
        strcpy(name, rhs.name);

        return *this;
    }

    // Destructor
    virtual ~A() {
        delete [] name;
    }
};

I have the subclass B with additional variable 'b':
class B : public A {
    int b;

    // Constructor
    B():A(),b(0){}

    // Assignment Operator
    virtual B& operator=(const B& rhs) {
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }

        delete [] name;
        name = new char[10];
        strcpy(name, rhs.name);

        b = rhs.b;

        return *this;
    }

    // Destructor
    virtual ~B() {
        delete [] name;
    }
};

I have the subclass C with additional member 'char* name':
class C : public A {
    int* c;

    // Constructor
    C():A() {
        c = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            c[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    // Assignment Operator
    virtual C& operator=(const C& rhs) {
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }

        delete [] name;
        name = new char[10];
        strcpy(name, rhs.name);

        delete [] c;
        c = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
            c[i] = rhs.c[i];
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // Destructor
    virtual ~C() {
        delete [] name;
        delete [] c;
    }
};

I wonder if this is the correct way to implement operator= and destructors for B and C.
Is there any way to call A's operator= or destructor in B or C, so I don't write assignment for all members again and again.

A is base class with a heap variable
B is a class derived from A, with additional 'int b'
C is a class derived from A, with additional 'char* name'


Why char *name;? You are going about this the wrong way. It's supposed to be std::string name; since every owning entity should mind its own resources.

@TedLyngmo It is how we are taught in university.

Ok, then it's wrong. Do it correctly by breaking it down into small owning classes. Every  resource owing class should be carefully crafted to keep track of the resource and free it when needed.

operator= is just a plain function really, and can be called as such from a parent like ParentClass::operator=(argument).

As for copy-constructors, you can use it just the same way you already invoke the default constructors, just pass the argument.

@Someprogrammerdude the question i've asked is not about that actually. Lets say I want to implement it for B or C as well. Should I write assignments for the members inherited from A every time?

@serkanertas It's just too much in one question. Solve resource management and you'll solve the rest too. If you make one RAII class, the composite of 1000 RAII classes comes free.

Side note on Assignment operators: Read about the Copy and Swap Idiom. It isn't always the most efficient solution at runtime, but at code-writing time, it's really hard to beat. Plus it is about as close to foolproof as you'll see in this lifetime. Simple and foolproof isn't a win you get often, so when you can take it, take it.

Generalization of Ted's point: Protect a resource as close to the resource as possible.

@JaMiT You are right, sorry for that.

As for calling the base class's destructor, you don't. C++ calls it automatically from the destructor of the derived class. You don't have to delete name[] in C::~C(). It will happen automatically when A::~A() is called, automatically.

To respond to the question as asked, yes, a derived class operator=() can call a base class operator=().  For example;
    B& operator=(const B& rhs) {
       A::operator=(rhs);
       b = rhs.b;
       return *this;  
    }

(and similarly for C).
However, this isn't a particularly good approach.   In the following, I'm going to address some concerns with your approach that you did NOT ask about.

It is not necessary that any of your operator=() be virtual.

It would be better to not declare or define B::operator=() at all.   That allows B::operator=() to be implicitly generated (e.g. by your compiler) and the implicitly generated version calls the base class version, and copy/assigns all member by value.   The only reason to roll your own is if the implicitly-generated operator=() is not suitable for your derived class.


Additionally, it is not necessary to do  the if (this == &rhs) in A::operator=().   Instead, it can be defined as
A &operator=(const A &rhs) {
    char *newname = new char [std::strlen(rhs.name) + 1];
    strcpy(newname, rhs.name);
    delete [] name;
    name = newname;
    return *this;
}

Apart from avoiding the this == &rhs test (which will produce different behaviour if A has an operator&()), this approach is also exception safe - if the new expression throws, the object is unchanged.
The only downside of this is that, temporarily, there is a minor additional memory usage (name, rhs.name, and newname all consume memory, before name is released and reassigned).
Using this approach, C::operator=() would be implemented to call A::operator=() and to allocate/copy/release c.
Furthermore, the destructors of B and C should generally not release As members.   When B and C are destructed, As constructor is called implicitly (so your approach will result in A::name being destroyed twice, which results in undefined behaviour).
Lastly, you can use standard containers (such as std::string, or std::vector<char>), and avoid the need for manual memory allocation (new and delete) entirely.   Look up "rule of zero C++" for more information.

Thank you Peter, you helped a lot!
